# Powershell if String.StartsWith() multiple strings

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and i am trying run some code if a string does not start with a certain character, however i can not get this to work with multiple characters.

This is the code that works fine.

```
 if (-Not $recdata.StartsWith("1"))
            {
                //mycode.
            }
```

But what i want is multiple checks like this

```
 if (-Not $recdata.StartsWith("1") -Or -Not $recdata.StartsWith("2"))
            {
                //mycode.
            }
```

But this does not work it breaks the whole function eventhough powershell does not throw any errors. I have tried multiple things but i cant find any solution

Comment: We would need to understand where is your input coming from. Can you provide us with a sample input and your expected output(s)?

Comment: Data comes over TCP as text. What i want is when i send for example 1 to the script over TCP that it does not execute my code. It does work when i use the first example i posted. but when i try to exclude 1 and 2 the whole code doesnt work anymore and my script executes the code even though i send 1 or 2

Comment: If what you need is to not run your code neither when $recdata starts with "1", neither "2", then you should change the -Or for an -And

Comment: You can also do `if( $recdata -match '^[^12]' ) { # your code if it does not start with 1 and 2 }`

Comment: How could i add even more checks to this? just add a 3 after the 2 or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MundoPeter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13830866/mundopeter) has pointed out the *logic flaw* in your approach - `-or` should be `-and` - and [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has offered an alternative based on the regex-based `-match` operator.

Let me offer the following PowerShell-idiomatic solutions, taking advantage of the fact that PowerShell's operators offer *negated* variants simply by prepending `not` to their names:

```
$recdata[0] -notin '1', '2' # check 1st char of LHS against RHS array
```

```
$recdata -notlike '[12]*'   # check LHS against wildcard expression
```

```
$recdata -notmatch '^[12]'  # check LHS against regex
```

See also:

- `-in`, the [is-the-LHS-contained-in-the-RHS-collection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin)
- `-like`, the [wildcard matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like)
- `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match)